# Queryset filter for part of a number

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a list of codes:

```
21000000 Code 1
21000001 Code 2
22000000 Code 3
22000001 Code 4
22002100 Code 5
```

The model for the code is:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I would like to filter only the codes that start with 2100XXXX.  When I use startswith, it doesn't seem to recognize number.  What is the proper way to right a queryset call to only filter for 2100XXXX.  Currently, my code is:

```
DB.objects.filter(code__startswith='2100')
```

This should pick up Code 1 and 2 and no others.

Thanks

Comment: Presumably your model field is a `CharField` or `TextField`? What is the queryset that's returned? Can you post the relevant part of your model?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony model added.

Comment: Is that the exact code you have? Your field is called `code_id` but your query uses `code`.

Comment: I'm not sure if these are typos, but you are using the wrong model in your query and you are using the wrong field. It should be `Category.objects.filter(code_id__startswith='2100')`

Comment: Are the codes made up of all numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your field `code_id` and your filter is: `code__startswith`

This should work:

```
DB.objects.filter(code_id__startswith='2100')
```